# Displaying empty state label in tableView with RxTableView , mvvm architecture

Tags: swift, mvvm

I am learning *rxswift* and I have a `ViewController` with a `tableView`.
I am using the MVVM architecture, so a `tableView` is bound to a `ViewModel` and it displays data well.

But I want put a `TableView` label empty state when I don't have data
and I don't know how to do it, if it's possible.

This is my code so far:

```
func bindViewModel() {    
    let inputs = viewModel.inputs
    let outputs = viewModel.outputs
    btnSomeAction.rx.action = inputs.someAction
    outputs.usersList
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "UserTableViewCell", cellType: UserTableViewCell.self)) { (_,element,cell) in
            cell.setData(name: element.name, avatar: element.avatar)
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Thanks to all for any help.
P.S.:
I know how to do it in a general table without `rx` with amount of element zero. The question is about `rxtable`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be converting the observable to a Driver, and returning the empty-state model like this:

```
   outputs.usersList
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
    .drive(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "UserTableViewCell", cellType: UserTableViewCell.self)) { (_,element,cell) in
        cell.setData(name: element.name, avatar: element.avatar)
}
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

As far as I know, a more complex solution would be using RxDataSources
[RxDataSources - How to add a custom empty cell when there's no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086529/rxdatasources-how-to-add-a-custom-empty-cell-when-theres-no-data)